# Can UIImageView make stretchable area like this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm going to use rounded corner box as 'container' of some `UIComponents` and, of course, it will requires multiple width and height.

my question is... is there any way to have just one PNG file with rounded corner but programatically stretch some area horizontally or vertically so it can be used in multiple `UIView`. if so, what `UIComponent` will be used to hold this image? is it `UIImageView`?

here's what I mean :

[image]

Comment: See the docs for `UIImage`.

Comment: You need: [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton"]  
   resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 16, 0, 16)];

Comment: is UIImage same with UIImageView? because what I see here in my UIComponents, Image View has UIImageView as a class.

Comment: A `UIImage` is what you show in a `UIImageView`.

Comment: @RobertHanson typically you don't want to resize the views like UIImageView, UIButton or whatever you are using, you want to resize the UIImage itself (like user:rydgaze mentioned), and all views honors the resizablity of the UIImage while they draw it. So the height and width are automatically adjusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below method to stretch imageview :

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];
img = [img stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:10];
```

and then its img into imageview.